# How to get only one part of the string without the end in bash

Tags: bash, grep, cat

I want to get only one part of the string new-profile-input, the part that I need is: "new-profile" without the "-input".

I tried like this:

```
cat automatization_test.sh |  grep -oh "\new-profile-input\w*" | grep -o "\-input\w*"
```

But, I get output:

`-input`

But, I need the first part not the last part of the string. Please note that the "new-profile" will always change, so that is why I have to focus on removing "-input" instead of getting only "new-profile".

Comment: Try `grep -Poh 'new-profile(?=-input)' automization_test.sh`.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for the fast reply, but that does not work, it does give me what I want, but I would have to specify "new-profile" and as I mentioned, that will change so I have to find another way. If you have any other idea how could I get "new-profile" without "-input" please let me know.

Comment: It is a good practice at SO to post a minimal reproducible example. Since we don't know what the file `automatization_test.sh` contains, we have to guess what you intend to do.

Comment: And it is not clear what you intend to do with `\w*`. Does your input contain backslashes or a repetition of the letter `w`? Do you mean repeating white space? Please look at the output of `cat automatization_test.sh |  grep -oh "\new-profile-input\w*"` to see if that part of the command is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can exclude everything after the last `-` slash where `-input` would be in your example string.

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' automatization_test.sh
new-profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If supported, you can use use `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions, match the whole line and use a positive lookahead to assert the last occurrence of `-` to the right.

**Note** that instead of using `cat`, you can also add the file at the end of the grep command instead.

```
grep -oP '.+(?=-)' automatization_test.sh
```

Output

```
new-profile
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVAgZs/1) for the match.

---

For a bit more specific match, you can use a positive lookahead to assert `-input` to the right and match non whitespace characters.

```
grep -oP '(?<!\S)\S+(?=-input(?!\S))' automatization_test.sh
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hSsSji/1) for the match.